# Incomplete file/copyright headers in Swift Package with Xcode 12 / 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, package, swift-package

Is there any way to automatically add package/target name and copyright + company name to the header when creating new files while developing a swift package with Xcode 12/13?

Just create a new package (File > New > Package) and add a new file to the sources (File > New > File).

Currently gives me this:

```
//
//  File.swift
//  
//
//  Created by User Name on 02.10.21.
//
```

instead of this (like when adding files to regular Xcode project):

```
//
//  File.swift
//  MyPackage
//
//  Created by User Name on 02.10.21.
//  Copyright © 2021 Company Name. All rights reserved.
//
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. create a file named IDETemplateMacros.plist. The content for this new file should like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>FILEHEADER</key>
    <string>
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___WORKSPACENAME___
// 
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright © 2021 Your Name Or Company. All rights reserved.
    </string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

2. put this file in one of the following locations,

   a. Has an impact on files created by the specified user (username) in the current workspace:

   ```
    <Your Package Root>/.swiftpm/xcode/package.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/<Your username>.xcuserdatad/IDETemplateMacros.plist
   ```

   b. Affects files created by all members in the current workspace:

   ```
   <Your Package Root>/.swiftpm/xcode/package.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDETemplateMacros.plist
   ```

Note:

- If you cannot see the `.swiftpm` folder even when "showing hidden files" is enabled, please double click the `Package.swift` file to open the package in Xcode. Then you will find the `.swiftpm` file created.
- you should right click 'show package content' of the package.xcworkspace to get inside
  [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGO9b.png)

Update:

- If you find this process to be very cumbersome, you can try using the tool I have created. ➡️ [spcreator](https://github.com/Lguanghui/SPCreator)

Answer (score 1):

Can add to Guanghui Liang's answer above that you can also add this to the `xcshareddata` folder like so:

1. Inside your `<Your Package Root>/.swiftpm/xcode/package.workspace/`, create a folder called `xcshareddata`.
2. Add the plist Guangui mentions in his answer to this folder.

Be aware that `xcuserdata` overwrites `xcshareddata`, so if you have the same file in both, Xcode will use the one in `xcuserdata`.